# How to Pause Elasticsearch in Elastic Cloud?

Tags: elasticsearch, cloud, elastic-cloud

Unable to pause Elasticsearch instance in **Elastic Cloud**.
In Documentation, It is mention for pause but unable to get any option on **Elastic Cloud Console**.

**Documentation Link** :-
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-enterprise/1.0/ece-maintenance-mode-clusters.html

Answer (score 2):

The documentation you refer to is not the Elastic Cloud documentation but the Elastic Cloud Enterprise (ECE) documentation, which is the underlying product that Elastic uses to operate Elastic Cloud.

It is not possible to directly pause instances from the Elastic Cloud Console UI. You can only **stop routing requests** to a given node by clicking on the three dots at the top right of your node.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I also observe same thing.
I just wanted to be sure.
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: But I tried both normal and Enterprise version. In Documentation, It says you can pause or stop routing. We got routing but not pause. If it is mention in documentation then from where we can pause Elasticsearch

Comment: Elastic Cloud Enterprise is not the Enterprise version of Elastic Cloud. They are two different things.